# Is “the best thing since sliced bread” supposed to be taken sarcastically?

Tags: meaning, popular-refrains

On one day my boss said that a tool I had created to speed up my work was “probably the best thing since sliced bread”. Neither one of us is a native english speaker and we don’t also have any similar saying in our language, so it was a direct word-to-word translation. I assume that his intentions was to praise the work I had done, but is that the correct usage of the phrase? I would say that sliced bread was not so great invention, and if I had used the phrase, I would have used it sarcastically.

Comment: Like anything, a word or phrase **can** be used sarcastically. But the phrase is not sarcastic in and of itself. If I say **I love you the best**, even such a phrase can be used sarcastically. And in Texas, I believe the standing version of your phrase uses *best* not *greatest.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a humorous or ironic exaggeration rather than sarcastic: it implies that what you created was excellent of its kind, even if it was not an earth-shattering invention.

The phrase (more often said in the US as “the *greatest* thing since sliced bread”; but ‘best’ has overtaken ‘greatest’ in BrE usage— see [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greatest+thing+since+sliced+bread%3Aeng_gb_2009%2Cbest+thing+since+sliced+bread%3Aeng_gb_2009%2Cgreatest+thing+since+sliced+bread%3Aeng_us_2009%2Cbest+thing+since+sliced+bread%3Aeng_us_2009&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20thing%20since%20sliced%20bread%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%20thing%20since%20sliced%20bread%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreatest%20thing%20since%20sliced%20bread%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%20thing%20since%20sliced%20bread%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0)) has its origin in the advertising slogan of the first company to market pre-sliced bread:

> Otto Frederick Rohwedder of Davenport, Iowa, USA invented the first loaf-at-a-time bread-slicing machine. A prototype he built in 1912 was destroyed in a fire and it was not until 1928 that Rohwedder had a fully working machine ready. The first commercial use of the machine was by the Chillicothe Baking Company of Chillicothe, Missouri, which produced their first slices on July 7, 1928. Their product, “Kleen Maid Sliced Bread”, proved a success. [...] The bread was advertised as ***“the greatest forward step in the baking industry since bread was wrapped.”*** —[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliced_bread), s.v. ‘Sliced Bread’; my emphasis

ADDED:
Drew points out, quite correctly, that I have too easily accepted Wikipedia’s assertion that the Chillicothe Baking Co. tag “led to the popular phrase, ‘the greatest thing since sliced bread’”. The actual origin is both more complicated and more obscure.

What actually happened was that pre-sliced bread, backed by aggressive marketing (see the ads below, from 1929 to the early 1930s), was an immediate and overwhelming success with consumers. Various sources report that by 1935 between two-thirds and 80% of bread sold was pre-sliced. Sliced bread was clearly a **great thing**.

The earliest version of the “since sliced bread” which anyone has located is the bottom ad below, from the Feb 16, 1940 *Burlington Daily Times-News*, in which Southern Bread’s announcement of a ‘twin-pack’ (a loaf packaged as two half-loaves) is accompanied by ‘testimonials’ including one from ‘Mother’: *Greatest convenience since sliced bread*.

[image]

An episode three years later suggests that Southern Bread did not invent this out of thin air. In 1943, during WWII, the Federal government imposed a ban on sliced bread, to conserve the steel going into slicing machines and the heavier waxed paper required by sliced bread. The public was outraged. Wikipedia quotes a letter to the *New York Times*:

> I should like to let you know how important sliced bread is to the morale and saneness of a household. My husband and four children are all in a rush during and after breakfast. Without ready-sliced bread I must do the slicing for toast—two pieces for each one—that’s ten. For their lunches I must cut by hand at least twenty slices, for two sandwiches apiece. Afterward I make my own toast. Twenty-two slices of bread to be cut in a hurry!

The ban was lifted in two months.

The “greatest thing” piece of the quote emerged within a very few years. Partridge, *Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, says “Services’, mostly army, ironic c.p. for any useful novelty: since mid-1950s. By 1980, > more widespread”. The earliest use I have found is a Google Books snippet from Nathaniel Benchley’s *Side Street*, published in 1950 “That Hermione,” Hale said, when the outer door had closed. “She's the greatest God-damned thing since sliced bread.” Benchley had served in the Navy in WWII.

But for what it’s worth, in another story in the same book Benchley also writes “She looked as though she'd be the greatest God-damned thing since 7-Up”. 7 Up was another marketing success story: the drink was launched by the Howdy Corporation in 1929 as “Bib-Label Lithiated Lemon-Lime Soda,” with a winged logo  [image: 7 up winged logo] echoing the description “Seven natural flavors blended into a savory, flavory drink with a real wallop.” The cumbersome name was subsequently shortened to “7 Up Lithiated Lemon Soda” and eventually to just “7 Up”; it was so successful that by 1936 the company itself changed its name to “The Seven-Up Company”. In the late 40s 7 Up was the third-best-selling soft drink in the world.

Perhaps Benchley, who was born in 1915 and witnessed the extraordinarily swift rise of sliced bread and 7 Up, should have the credit for inventing this catchphrase.

---

<sup>Image Sources:

Chillicothe Baking: futurechallenges-dot-org (A link to this source is "not allowed" by SE.)

Mrs. Baird’s: [http://lospastelesderosa.blogspot.com/2012/11/pan-de-molde-con-cara-de-buho-origen.html]

Butter-Krust: [http://mysapl.wordpress.com/2014/10/08/october-8-in-san-antonio-history-5/]

A&P Grandmother's Bread: [http://www.pinterest.com/genealogybank/old-newspaper-ads/]

Wonder Bread: [http://lincolnliontales.com/721/oped/a-dive-into-the-past-1920s/#prettyPhoto] and [http://www.pinterest.com/thewonderbread/our-wonder-ful-history/]

Burlington: [http://www.firstmention.com/slicedbread/]

7 Up: [http://jaced.com/2005/06/23/the-history-of-7up/]</sup>

Comment: FWIW - You show no support for the claim that the phrase has its origin in that advertising slogan. All you show is that pre-sliced bread became a commodity at some point and there was an ad campaign that said the sliced-bread product was the best thing since wrapped bread.

Comment: @Drew I have attempted to address your very reasonable objection.

Comment: Also OED "[**the best (or greatest, etc.) thing since sliced bread** : an expression of enthusiastic appreciation, esp. of a new invention or discovery](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/181731)". Your earliest example antedates OED's earliest 'best thing since sliced bread' - you should write in.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my concern. I wonder (ignorance on my part): did load-slicers, and thus the expression, perhaps exist before the mass-marketing and retailing of **industrially produced & packaged** sliced loaves? You can go to a baker (now, at least), ask for a loaf, and ask that it optionally be sliced. Were loaf slicers not available in bakeries before the mass-marketing of centrally baked & sliced loaves? I wonder. My guess is that the invention came first and was used here and there locally, and not just in some big industrial bakery. (Shades of *le fil a couper le beurre*.)

Comment: @Drew My guess is that such slicers did not exist. Users of the Rohwedder slicer had to combat considerable pushback from colleagues who said presliced bread would go stale too quickly (one of the reasons Rohwedder incorporated a wrapping process, too), which suggests that bakers were not at that time using such a thing. And the long time it took for Rohwedder to develop and capitalize his invention suggests that he had no existing model. The slicers which did exist appear to have been designed to remove one slice at time, like the meat slicers modern delis use.

Comment: We are apparently each guessing. ;-) I don't think that your local baker would worry about sliced bread going stale. Especially back then, when people more commonly bought bread more often and the bread was often denser and so did not go stale so  quickly. But again, we're both guessing, I guess. In my case, I'm still wondering about this.

Comment: I remember hating "sliced bread" as a child (preferring rolls), so telling me that something was "the greatest thing since sliced bread" was a real "turn-off to me, even well into my adult life.

Answer (score -2):

It is clear to me that the correct origin of the phrase "the greatest thing since sliced bread" originated from the sitcom *Friends*. Joey uses the statement when attempting to criticize an actress, remarking that just because she studied at Harvard, she thinks she's the greatest thing since sliced bread.

The articles I checked seem either not to know the origin or to make guesses (like Wikipedia's assertion), but every reference I have found to the saying indicates that it is older than the episode of *Friends* in question.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question, which asks if the saying is meant sarcastically or not. The questioner is only inquiring about the origin in an indirect way; more specifically, as to whether or not it helps indicate the sincerity of the phrase (or lack thereof). Also, the information provided is confusing. On the one hand, you contend that the saying originates from "Friends," but on the other hand, you mention that every reference you've found is OLDER than the episode you're citing. So it's unclear exactly what you're attempting to say here.

Comment: StoneyB's answer to this question includes an advertisement from 1940 that uses the expression. The TV series _Friends_ debuted in 1994—which makes it at least 54 years too late to have been the origin of the expression, even if the 1940 ad was indeed the original instance and the instance you refer to was from the first season of the TV show..